# Выполнить html, css, js написанные в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно сделать простой скрипт?

Например: три колонки где можно вводить код, *html*, *css*, *js* и четвертая колонка, где выводится результат.

Для тестирования *html*, *css*, *js*, подобно тому, что есть на сайтах **codepen.io/pen** и **jsfiddle.net**?

Comment: А вы не пробовали сами посмотреть как устроен jsfiddle? ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

В целом реализация не требует никакой серверной части. С сервера стоит только загружать предварительный контент в нужные элементы, а также сохранять их при необходимости. В остальном в сервере необходимости нет.

Уже была рекомендация использовать iFrame.

Вот мой пример, который делал когда-то для своих задач http://jsfiddle.net/r1o8n298/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>HTML</h1>
    <textarea id="html"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>CSS</h1>
    <textarea id="css"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>JavaScript</h1>
    <textarea id="js"></textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var widgetTpl = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html>" +
    "<head>" +
    "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
    "<title>Widget</title>" +
    "<\/head>" +
    "<body>" +
    "<\/body>" +
    "<\/html>";
var outputFrame = document.querySelector("#output");
var outputDoc = outputFrame.contentDocument;

var htmlEditor = document.querySelector("#html");
var cssEditor = document.querySelector("#css");
var jsEditor = document.querySelector("#js");
var editors = [htmlEditor, cssEditor, jsEditor];

var prepareSource = function () {
    var src = widgetTpl;
    var htmlStr = htmlEditor.value;
    var cssStr = "<style>" + cssEditor.value + "<\/style>";
    var jsStr = "<script>" + jsEditor.value + "<\/script>";

    src = src.replace("<\/head>", cssStr + "<\/head>");
    src = src.replace("<\/head>", jsStr + "<\/head>");
    src = src.replace("<\/body>", htmlStr + "<\/body>");
    return src;
}

var render = function (source) {
    outputDoc.open();
    outputDoc.write(source);
    outputDoc.close();
}
var lastCode = prepareSource();
render(lastCode);
editors.forEach(function (editor) {
    editor.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
        var source = prepareSource();
        if (lastCode !== source) {
            render(source);
            lastCode = source;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Событие загрузки документа нельзя использовать в этом варианте. Такой код не сработает: `window.onload=function () { console.log(1) }` - у меня именно для этого адрес iframe'а меняется.

Comment: @Aries В вашем пример почему-то не работает js и с кнопкой показа результата, на мой взгляд более удобно.

Comment: @Muson со скриптом, там опечатка была: отсутствовал закрывающий тег. По поводу кнопки - зависит от задачи. В моем случае была необходимость реализации реалтайм обновления. Но доработка примера для клика по кнопке не составляет труда в целом.

Comment: @Aries Можешь показать пример, как доделать кнопочку для вывода результата.

Comment: @Muson, не буду приводить листинг кода сюда, вот готовый пример с кнопкой http://jsfiddle.net/r1o8n298/4/

Answer (score 18):

Думаю, простейший вариант такой, причём без сервера (и даже без jQuery!):

```js
document.getElementById("run").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  function prepare(content) {
    return "document.write('" +
        content
          .replace(/[\\']/g, "\\$&").replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/<\/script/g, "<\\/script")
          .replace(/%/g, "%25").replace(/#/g, "%23") +
      "');";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("res").src = "data:text/html,<!doctype html><title>Demo</title><script>" + 
    prepare("<style>" + document.getElementById("css").value + "</style>") +
    prepare(document.getElementById("html").value) +
    prepare("<script>" + document.getElementById("js").value + "<\/script>") +
    "<\/script>";
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

textarea, iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#run {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section><textarea id=html></textarea></section>
<section><textarea id=css></textarea></section>
<section><textarea id=js></textarea></section>
<section><iframe id=res src=about:blank></iframe></section>
<button id=run>Run</button>
```

Работает в Хромиумах, FF и Опере 12.
А вот в IE не работает. Совсем. И в Edge. Так и не научились открывать страницу по data-uri.

Comment: Всё таки с фреймом проще) Полностью согласен

Comment: @Qwertiy Ваш скрипт работает, только есть один минус, когда вставляю 'css' код, скрипт перестает работать.

Comment: @Muson, у тебя `#` в css... Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @Muson, готово.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67776/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy--html-css-js---textarea).

Answer (score 9):

Используйте iframe для 4го окна. Не уверен, что это будет работать, но я бы делал так:

```
$script = $('textarea.javascript');
$style = $('textarea.css');
$html = $('textarea.html');
$('iframe body).append($html);
$('iframe script).append($script);
$('iframe style).append($style);
```

Comment: Можете объяснить более подробно

Comment: @Muson, легче лёгкого. С каждого окна берём текст и формируем html  страницу, которую затем загружаем в iframe(в четвёртое окно). Результирующая HTML страница обязательно состоит из HEAD, куда мы запихиваем текст из окна CSS, также она включает в себя BODY, в который мы запихиваем текст из окна HTML и наконец под BODY вставляем текст из окна JS. Кажется так.

Comment: `onload` внутри фрейма работать не будет. А ещё у тебя опечатки в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Структура примерно такая

```
<div id='usercode' style='display : inline-block'>
    <textarea id='html'></textarea>
    <textarea id='css'></textarea>
    <textarea id='js'></textarea>
</div>
<div id='result' style='display : inline-block'></div>
```

После события `onkeyup` в одном из `textarea` Вы просто вызываете функцию, которая коллекционирует данные с Ваших `textarea` по `id`:

`var html = $('#html').val(); //и т.д`

После чего, генерируете переменную/объект которая будет помещать в себе все данные для результата и в конце просто в блок выводите всё с помощью `('#result').html(page_data);`

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 1**

Написал такую структуру и всё работает:

```js
 function serializeBox(){
        var page = "<style>" + $('#css').val() + "<\/style><script>" + $('#js').val() + "<\/script>" + $('#html').val();
        $('#frame').html(page);
    }
```

```css
 div div{
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    div{
        padding : 10px;
        margin : 10px;
    }

    #frame{
        border: 1px solid silver;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <div>
        <textarea id="html" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="css" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="js" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button onclick="serializeBox()">Run</button>
    </div>
</div><div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top" id="frame">

</div>
```

Да, не `iframe`'овый вариант. Но как базис для фидла, думаю, вполне сойдет

Comment: Не годится - скрипты будут выполняться в рамках твоей страницы, а не той разметки, которую указал пользователь.

Comment: Сейчас как раз тестирую всё это.

Comment: @saturn, а конкатенация строчек?)

Comment: @Qwertiy, но как база, может сойти